# Implementing geometry_columns view in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, geometry

(We're using MSSQL Server 2014 as far as I know)

I have never seen a good solution for maintaining a geometry_columns table in MSSQL Server. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71558 never got figured out, and even if it did, the PostGIS approach of using a view (rather than a table) is a much better solution.

With that said, I can't seem to figure out how to implement the basics of how this might work.

The basic schema of the geometry_columns view - from PostGIS is:

[image]

(the DDL is a bit more complicated, but can be provided if need be)

MS SQL Server will allow you to query your information_schema table to show tables with a 'geometry' data type:

```
select * 
FROM information_schema.columns 
where data_type = 'geometry'
```

I'm imagining the geometry_columns view could be defined with something similar to the following, but I can't figure out how to get the information about the geometry columns to populate in the query:

```
SELECT 
TABLE_CATALOG as f_table_catalog
, TABLE_SCHEMA as f_table_schema
, table_name as f_table_name 
, COLUMN_NAME as f_geometry_column

/*how to deal with these in view?
, geometry_column.STDimension() as coord_dimension
, geometry_column.STSrid as srid
, geometry_column.STGeometryType() as type
*/

FROM information_schema.columns where data_type = 'geometry'
```

I'm hung up as to how the three ST operators can dynamically report the dimension, srid, and geometry type in the view when trying to query from the information_schema table. Perhaps this is a SQL problem more than anything, but I can't wrap my head around it for some reason.

Here's what the PostGIS geometry columns table looks like:

[image]

Also please let me know if this question a) could be asked differently because it is a general SQL question and/or b) it belongs on another forum (GIS.SE didn't have an answer, as I believe this is more on the database side than spatial/GIS)

Comment: By version 12 do you mean 2014?

Comment: @Larnu thanks I've made the update

Comment: I'm confused by what a single row in this view is supposed to represent. The `coord_dimension`, `srid`, and `type` are properties of an *instance*, so a given table with a `geometry` column could have multiple different values of these in its rows. Should this view have one row per `geometry` column defined, or one row per row-in-a-table-with-a-`geometry`-column ?

Comment: @AakashM I would treat this as each table having a single geometry type - granted that a table could have multiple, but not knowing exactly how PostGIS would handle the situation you've described with multiple geometry columns or rows with multiple geometry types - that may change... would the PostGIS DDL help with this? I've also added a screen shot of the output of the PostGIS geometry_columns table. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a little reading, it seems that PostGIS - as befits a dedicated GIS system - is a little more clever than SQL Server, when it comes to `geometry` columns. It looks like in PostGIS you can say that a particular `geometry` column will only *ever* contain, say, a `POINT`, or a `LINESTRING`. This is how the `geometry_columns` view can then be more specific about the columns it is describing.

I don't believe it is possible to readily constrain a SQL Server `geometry` in this way (triggers or constraints might allow, but would be messy). PostGIS *can* have a general `geometry` column with no further restriction. Let's suppose you're happy for your SQL Server `geometry_columns` view to return the dimension, SRID, and type based on an arbitrary row of data.

We can get the column metadata out of the catalog views, but I think the only way to do the necessary querying to *also* get the geometry metadata is with dynamic SQL. This rules out views and functions. I can do you a stored procedure though:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetGeometryColumns
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = ( SELECT 
STUFF((
          SELECT ' UNION ALL ' + Query
          FROM 
( SELECT
    'SELECT ''' + s.name + ''' SchemaName' 
        + ', ''' + t.name + ''' TableName' 
        + ', ''' + c.name + ''' ColumnName'
        + ', ( SELECT TOP (1) ' + c.name + '.STDimension() FROM ' + s.name + '.' + t.name + ') Dimension'
        + ', ( SELECT TOP (1) ' + c.name + '.STSrid FROM ' + s.name + '.' + t.name + ') SRID'
        + ', ( SELECT TOP (1) ' + c.name + '.STGeometryType() FROM ' + s.name + '.' + t.name + ') GeometryType'
    AS Query
FROM
    sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE
    system_type_id = 240
) GeometryColumn

          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 10, '')
);

EXEC ( @sql );

END
```

This builds a SQL statement which is a `UNION` of `SELECT`s, one for each `geometry` column defined in the database. Note that I'm using the `sys.` catalog views, which [for SQL Server are better than using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Each of the individual `SELECT`s that this builds will return the name of the column, plus metadata from the value in the first row (artibtarily picked).

The sproc then executes the statements its built, and returns.

To use:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, Region geometry
)
;

CREATE TABLE T2 (
Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, Source geometry
, Destination geometry
)
;

INSERT T1 VALUES ( 1, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 3 3, 3 1, 1 1))', 4236)) ;

INSERT T2 VALUES ( 10
                    , geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(1.3 2.4)', 4236) 
                    , geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(2.6 2.5)', 4236)) ;
```

then simply

```
EXEC GetGeometryColumns;
```

to get

```
SchemaName TableName ColumnName  Dimension   SRID        GeometryType
---------- --------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------
dbo        T1        Region      2           4236        Polygon
dbo        T2        Source      0           4236        Point
dbo        T2        Destination 0           4236        Point
```

---

If you want the results in a table, you can for example:

```
DECLARE @geometryColumn TABLE
(
    SchemaName sysname
    , TableName sysname
    , ColumnName sysname
    , Dimension int
    , SRID int
    , GeometryType nvarchar(100)
);

INSERT @geometryColumn EXEC GetGeometryColumns

SELECT * FROM @geometryColumn
```

---

I'd be interested to see if anyone can get the necessary logic into an actual `VIEW`...

Comment: I greatly appreciate the time and effort you put in to this answer. I'm going to mark it as the answer and pick over it during the coming week or so... Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: As a follow-up, we did get something very similar to work on our end, and it solved the problem! Thanks again for providing this solution!!!